# How can you uniquify context-root on jBoss

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

Say I have a simple j2EE ear:

```
foo.ear
- foo.war
```

I would like to deploy the same ear twice so I rename the ear:

```
bar.ear
- foo.war
```

The `META-INF\application.xml` file looks like this:

```
<application>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>foo.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/baz</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

When I deploy there is a collison, both apps will try to mount at `http://localhost:8080/baz`. Is there a way to prefix the ear name to the context-root to get `foo/baz` and `bar/baz`?

Answer (score 3):

How about setting it at build time, by generating the *application.xml*? Ant can do this easily with a filter, on

```
<context-root>@context.root@</context-root>
```

In the Ant build script, do:

```
<copy todir="${ear.dir}/META-INF" file="${ear}/META-INF/application.xml" overwrite="true">
    <filterset>
        <filter token="context.root" value="${context.root}" />
    </filterset>
</copy>
```